# Failing to install Visual C++ Redistributable for Visual Studio 2015 on POSReady 7

Tags: windows, visual-studio-2015

We are not able to successfully install "Visual C++ Redistributable for Visual Studio 2015" on our Windows Embedded POSReady 7 (64 bit) boxes. We tried both the 32 bit and 64 bit version from here, but to no avail:

https://www.microsoft.com/de-de/download/details.aspx?id=48145

What we get is this error message:

> "One or more issues caused the setup to fail. Please fix the issues
>   and then retry setup. For more information see the log file.
>   0x80240017 - Unspecified error."

And this is the contents of the log file:

```
[0D78:0704][2016-06-27T13:02:15]i001: Burn v3.7.3813.0, Windows v6.1 (Build 7601: Service Pack 1), path: C:\Temp\vc_redist.x86.exe, cmdline: ''
[0D78:0704][2016-06-27T13:02:15]i000: Setting string variable 'WixBundleLog' to value 'C:\Users\AWEK_S~1\AppData\Local\Temp\dd_vcredist_x86_20160627130215.log'
[0D78:0704][2016-06-27T13:02:15]i000: Setting string variable 'WixBundleOriginalSource' to value 'C:\Temp\vc_redist.x86.exe'
[0D78:0704][2016-06-27T13:02:15]i000: Setting string variable 'WixBundleOriginalSourceFolder' to value 'C:\Temp\'
[0D78:0704][2016-06-27T13:02:15]i000: Setting string variable 'WixBundleName' to value 'Microsoft Visual C++ 2015 Redistributable (x86) - 14.0.23026'
[0D78:0704][2016-06-27T13:02:15]i100: Detect begin, 10 packages
[0D78:0704][2016-06-27T13:02:15]i000: File search: windows_uCRT_DetectKey, did not find path: C:\Windows\system32\api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0.dll
[0D78:0704][2016-06-27T13:02:15]i000: File search: windows_uCRT_DetectKeyExists, did not find path: C:\Windows\system32\api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0.dll
[0D78:0704][2016-06-27T13:02:15]i000: Setting numeric variable 'windows_uCRT_DetectKeyExists' to value 0
[0D78:0704][2016-06-27T13:02:15]i052: Condition '(windows_uCRT_DetectKeyExists AND windows_uCRT_DetectKey >= v10.0.10137.0)' evaluates to false.
[0D78:0704][2016-06-27T13:02:15]i052: Condition '(windows_uCRT_DetectKeyExists AND windows_uCRT_DetectKey >= v10.0.10137.0)' evaluates to false.
[0D78:0704][2016-06-27T13:02:15]i052: Condition '(windows_uCRT_DetectKeyExists AND windows_uCRT_DetectKey >= v10.0.10137.0)' evaluates to false.
[0D78:0704][2016-06-27T13:02:15]i052: Condition '(windows_uCRT_DetectKeyExists AND windows_uCRT_DetectKey >= v10.0.10137.0)' evaluates to false.
[0D78:0704][2016-06-27T13:02:15]i052: Condition '(windows_uCRT_DetectKeyExists AND windows_uCRT_DetectKey >= v10.0.10137.0)' evaluates to false.
[0D78:0704][2016-06-27T13:02:15]i052: Condition '(windows_uCRT_DetectKeyExists AND windows_uCRT_DetectKey >= v10.0.10137.0)' evaluates to false.
[0D78:0704][2016-06-27T13:02:15]i052: Condition '(windows_uCRT_DetectKeyExists AND windows_uCRT_DetectKey >= v10.0.10137.0)' evaluates to false.
[0D78:0704][2016-06-27T13:02:15]i052: Condition '(windows_uCRT_DetectKeyExists AND windows_uCRT_DetectKey >= v10.0.10137.0)' evaluates to false.
[0D78:0704][2016-06-27T13:02:15]i101: Detected package: vcRuntimeMinimum_x86, state: Absent, cached: None
[0D78:0704][2016-06-27T13:02:15]i101: Detected package: vcRuntimeAdditional_x86, state: Absent, cached: None
[0D78:0704][2016-06-27T13:02:15]i101: Detected package: Windows81_x86, state: Absent, cached: None
[0D78:0704][2016-06-27T13:02:15]i101: Detected package: Windows81_x64, state: Absent, cached: None
[0D78:0704][2016-06-27T13:02:15]i101: Detected package: Windows8_x86, state: Absent, cached: None
[0D78:0704][2016-06-27T13:02:15]i101: Detected package: Windows8_x64, state: Absent, cached: None
[0D78:0704][2016-06-27T13:02:15]i101: Detected package: Windows7_MSU_x86, state: Absent, cached: None
[0D78:0704][2016-06-27T13:02:15]i101: Detected package: Windows7_MSU_x64, state: Absent, cached: None
[0D78:0704][2016-06-27T13:02:15]i101: Detected package: WindowsVista_MSU_x86, state: Absent, cached: None
[0D78:0704][2016-06-27T13:02:15]i101: Detected package: WindowsVista_MSU_x64, state: Absent, cached: None
[0D78:0704][2016-06-27T13:02:15]i052: Condition 'VersionNT >= v6.0 OR (VersionNT = v5.1 AND ServicePackLevel >= 2) OR (VersionNT = v5.2 AND ServicePackLevel >= 1)' evaluates to true.
[0D78:0704][2016-06-27T13:02:15]i199: Detect complete, result: 0x0
[0D78:0704][2016-06-27T13:02:17]i200: Plan begin, 10 packages, action: Install
[0D78:0704][2016-06-27T13:02:17]i000: Setting string variable 'WixBundleRollbackLog_vcRuntimeMinimum_x86' to value 'C:\Users\AWEK_S~1\AppData\Local\Temp\dd_vcredist_x86_20160627130215_000_vcRuntimeMinimum_x86_rollback.log'
[0D78:0704][2016-06-27T13:02:17]i000: Setting string variable 'WixBundleLog_vcRuntimeMinimum_x86' to value 'C:\Users\AWEK_S~1\AppData\Local\Temp\dd_vcredist_x86_20160627130215_000_vcRuntimeMinimum_x86.log'
[0D78:0704][2016-06-27T13:02:17]i000: Setting string variable 'WixBundleRollbackLog_vcRuntimeAdditional_x86' to value 'C:\Users\AWEK_S~1\AppData\Local\Temp\dd_vcredist_x86_20160627130215_001_vcRuntimeAdditional_x86_rollback.log'
[0D78:0704][2016-06-27T13:02:17]i000: Setting string variable 'WixBundleLog_vcRuntimeAdditional_x86' to value 'C:\Users\AWEK_S~1\AppData\Local\Temp\dd_vcredist_x86_20160627130215_001_vcRuntimeAdditional_x86.log'
[0D78:0704][2016-06-27T13:02:17]i052: Condition 'VersionNT = v6.3 AND NOT VersionNT64' evaluates to false.
[0D78:0704][2016-06-27T13:02:17]w321: Skipping dependency registration on package with no dependency providers: Windows81_x86
[0D78:0704][2016-06-27T13:02:17]i052: Condition 'VersionNT = v6.3 AND VersionNT64' evaluates to false.
[0D78:0704][2016-06-27T13:02:17]w321: Skipping dependency registration on package with no dependency providers: Windows81_x64
[0D78:0704][2016-06-27T13:02:17]i052: Condition 'VersionNT = v6.2 AND NOT VersionNT64' evaluates to false.
[0D78:0704][2016-06-27T13:02:17]w321: Skipping dependency registration on package with no dependency providers: Windows8_x86
[0D78:0704][2016-06-27T13:02:17]i052: Condition 'VersionNT = v6.2 AND VersionNT64' evaluates to false.
[0D78:0704][2016-06-27T13:02:17]w321: Skipping dependency registration on package with no dependency providers: Windows8_x64
[0D78:0704][2016-06-27T13:02:17]i052: Condition 'VersionNT = v6.1 AND NOT VersionNT64' evaluates to false.
[0D78:0704][2016-06-27T13:02:17]w321: Skipping dependency registration on package with no dependency providers: Windows7_MSU_x86
[0D78:0704][2016-06-27T13:02:17]i052: Condition 'VersionNT = v6.1 AND VersionNT64' evaluates to true.
[0D78:0704][2016-06-27T13:02:17]w321: Skipping dependency registration on package with no dependency providers: Windows7_MSU_x64
[0D78:0704][2016-06-27T13:02:17]i052: Condition 'VersionNT = v6.0 AND NOT VersionNT64' evaluates to false.
[0D78:0704][2016-06-27T13:02:17]w321: Skipping dependency registration on package with no dependency providers: WindowsVista_MSU_x86
[0D78:0704][2016-06-27T13:02:17]i052: Condition 'VersionNT = v6.0 AND VersionNT64' evaluates to false.
[0D78:0704][2016-06-27T13:02:17]w321: Skipping dependency registration on package with no dependency providers: WindowsVista_MSU_x64
[0D78:0704][2016-06-27T13:02:17]i201: Planned package: vcRuntimeMinimum_x86, state: Absent, default requested: Present, ba requested: Present, execute: Install, rollback: Uninstall, cache: Yes, uncache: No, dependency: Register
[0D78:0704][2016-06-27T13:02:17]i201: Planned package: vcRuntimeAdditional_x86, state: Absent, default requested: Present, ba requested: Present, execute: Install, rollback: Uninstall, cache: Yes, uncache: No, dependency: Register
[0D78:0704][2016-06-27T13:02:17]i201: Planned package: Windows81_x86, state: Absent, default requested: Absent, ba requested: Absent, execute: None, rollback: None, cache: No, uncache: No, dependency: None
[0D78:0704][2016-06-27T13:02:17]i201: Planned package: Windows81_x64, state: Absent, default requested: Absent, ba requested: Absent, execute: None, rollback: None, cache: No, uncache: No, dependency: None
[0D78:0704][2016-06-27T13:02:17]i201: Planned package: Windows8_x86, state: Absent, default requested: Absent, ba requested: Absent, execute: None, rollback: None, cache: No, uncache: No, dependency: None
[0D78:0704][2016-06-27T13:02:17]i201: Planned package: Windows8_x64, state: Absent, default requested: Absent, ba requested: Absent, execute: None, rollback: None, cache: No, uncache: No, dependency: None
[0D78:0704][2016-06-27T13:02:17]i201: Planned package: Windows7_MSU_x86, state: Absent, default requested: Absent, ba requested: Absent, execute: None, rollback: None, cache: No, uncache: No, dependency: None
[0D78:0704][2016-06-27T13:02:17]i201: Planned package: Windows7_MSU_x64, state: Absent, default requested: Present, ba requested: Present, execute: Install, rollback: Uninstall, cache: Yes, uncache: No, dependency: None
[0D78:0704][2016-06-27T13:02:17]i201: Planned package: WindowsVista_MSU_x86, state: Absent, default requested: Absent, ba requested: Absent, execute: None, rollback: None, cache: No, uncache: No, dependency: None
[0D78:0704][2016-06-27T13:02:17]i201: Planned package: WindowsVista_MSU_x64, state: Absent, default requested: Absent, ba requested: Absent, execute: None, rollback: None, cache: No, uncache: No, dependency: None
[0D78:0704][2016-06-27T13:02:17]i299: Plan complete, result: 0x0
[0D78:0704][2016-06-27T13:02:17]i300: Apply begin
[11C0:0BBC][2016-06-27T13:02:19]i360: Creating a system restore point.
[11C0:0BBC][2016-06-27T13:02:19]w363: Could not create system restore point, error: 0x80070422. Continuing...
[11C0:0BBC][2016-06-27T13:02:19]i370: Session begin, registration key: SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\{74d0e5db-b326-4dae-a6b2-445b9de1836e}, options: 0x7, disable resume: No
[11C0:0BBC][2016-06-27T13:02:19]i000: Caching bundle from: 'C:\Users\AWEK_S~1\AppData\Local\Temp\{74d0e5db-b326-4dae-a6b2-445b9de1836e}\.be\VC_redist.x86.exe' to: 'C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\{74d0e5db-b326-4dae-a6b2-445b9de1836e}\VC_redist.x86.exe'
[11C0:0BBC][2016-06-27T13:02:19]i320: Registering bundle dependency provider: {74d0e5db-b326-4dae-a6b2-445b9de1836e}, version: 14.0.23026.0
[11C0:0BBC][2016-06-27T13:02:19]i371: Updating session, registration key: SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\{74d0e5db-b326-4dae-a6b2-445b9de1836e}, resume: Active, restart initiated: No, disable resume: No
[11C0:02EC][2016-06-27T13:02:34]i304: Verified existing payload: vcRuntimeMinimum_x86 at path: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\.unverified\vcRuntimeMinimum_x86.
[11C0:02EC][2016-06-27T13:02:34]i305: Verified acquired payload: vcRuntimeMinimum_x86 at path: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\.unverified\vcRuntimeMinimum_x86, moving to: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\{A2563E55-3BEC-3828-8D67-E5E8B9E8B675}v14.0.23026\packages\vcRuntimeMinimum_x86\vc_runtimeMinimum_x86.msi.
[11C0:02EC][2016-06-27T13:02:34]i304: Verified existing payload: cab54A5CABBE7274D8A22EB58060AAB7623 at path: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\.unverified\cab54A5CABBE7274D8A22EB58060AAB7623.
[11C0:02EC][2016-06-27T13:02:34]i305: Verified acquired payload: cab54A5CABBE7274D8A22EB58060AAB7623 at path: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\.unverified\cab54A5CABBE7274D8A22EB58060AAB7623, moving to: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\{A2563E55-3BEC-3828-8D67-E5E8B9E8B675}v14.0.23026\packages\vcRuntimeMinimum_x86\cab1.cab.
[11C0:02EC][2016-06-27T13:02:34]i304: Verified existing payload: vcRuntimeAdditional_x86 at path: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\.unverified\vcRuntimeAdditional_x86.
[11C0:02EC][2016-06-27T13:02:34]i305: Verified acquired payload: vcRuntimeAdditional_x86 at path: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\.unverified\vcRuntimeAdditional_x86, moving to: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\{BE960C1C-7BAD-3DE6-8B1A-2616FE532845}v14.0.23026\packages\vcRuntimeAdditional_x86\vc_runtimeAdditional_x86.msi.
[11C0:02EC][2016-06-27T13:02:34]i304: Verified existing payload: cabB3E1576D1FEFBB979E13B1A5379E0B16 at path: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\.unverified\cabB3E1576D1FEFBB979E13B1A5379E0B16.
[11C0:02EC][2016-06-27T13:02:34]i305: Verified acquired payload: cabB3E1576D1FEFBB979E13B1A5379E0B16 at path: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\.unverified\cabB3E1576D1FEFBB979E13B1A5379E0B16, moving to: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\{BE960C1C-7BAD-3DE6-8B1A-2616FE532845}v14.0.23026\packages\vcRuntimeAdditional_x86\cab1.cab.
[11C0:02EC][2016-06-27T13:02:34]i304: Verified existing payload: Windows7_MSU_x64 at path: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\.unverified\Windows7_MSU_x64.
[11C0:02EC][2016-06-27T13:02:34]i305: Verified acquired payload: Windows7_MSU_x64 at path: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\.unverified\Windows7_MSU_x64, moving to: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\42D5BEC7DDFBD49E76467529CBC2868987BF8460\packages\Patch\x64\Windows6.1-KB2999226-x64.msu.
[11C0:0BBC][2016-06-27T13:02:34]i301: Applying execute package: vcRuntimeMinimum_x86, action: Install, path: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\{A2563E55-3BEC-3828-8D67-E5E8B9E8B675}v14.0.23026\packages\vcRuntimeMinimum_x86\vc_runtimeMinimum_x86.msi, arguments: ' MSIFASTINSTALL="7" NOVSUI="1"'
[0D78:0704][2016-06-27T13:02:35]i319: Applied execute package: vcRuntimeMinimum_x86, result: 0x0, restart: None
[11C0:0BBC][2016-06-27T13:02:35]i325: Registering dependency: {74d0e5db-b326-4dae-a6b2-445b9de1836e} on package provider: Microsoft.VS.VC_RuntimeMinimumVSU_x86,v14, package: vcRuntimeMinimum_x86
[11C0:0BBC][2016-06-27T13:02:35]i301: Applying execute package: vcRuntimeAdditional_x86, action: Install, path: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\{BE960C1C-7BAD-3DE6-8B1A-2616FE532845}v14.0.23026\packages\vcRuntimeAdditional_x86\vc_runtimeAdditional_x86.msi, arguments: ' MSIFASTINSTALL="7" NOVSUI="1"'
[0D78:0704][2016-06-27T13:02:36]i319: Applied execute package: vcRuntimeAdditional_x86, result: 0x0, restart: None
[11C0:0BBC][2016-06-27T13:02:36]i325: Registering dependency: {74d0e5db-b326-4dae-a6b2-445b9de1836e} on package provider: Microsoft.VS.VC_RuntimeAdditionalVSU_x86,v14, package: vcRuntimeAdditional_x86
[11C0:0BBC][2016-06-27T13:02:36]i301: Applying execute package: Windows7_MSU_x64, action: Install, path: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\42D5BEC7DDFBD49E76467529CBC2868987BF8460\packages\Patch\x64\Windows6.1-KB2999226-x64.msu, arguments: '"C:\Windows\SysNative\wusa.exe" "C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\42D5BEC7DDFBD49E76467529CBC2868987BF8460\packages\Patch\x64\Windows6.1-KB2999226-x64.msu" /quiet /norestart'
[11C0:0BBC][2016-06-27T13:02:39]e000: Error 0x80240017: Failed to execute MSU package.
[0D78:0704][2016-06-27T13:02:39]e000: Error 0x80240017: Failed to configure per-machine MSU package.
[0D78:0704][2016-06-27T13:02:39]i319: Applied execute package: Windows7_MSU_x64, result: 0x80240017, restart: None
[0D78:0704][2016-06-27T13:02:39]e000: Error 0x80240017: Failed to execute MSU package.
[11C0:0BBC][2016-06-27T13:02:39]i372: Session end, registration key: SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\{74d0e5db-b326-4dae-a6b2-445b9de1836e}, resume: ARP, restart: None, disable resume: No
[11C0:0BBC][2016-06-27T13:02:39]i371: Updating session, registration key: SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\{74d0e5db-b326-4dae-a6b2-445b9de1836e}, resume: ARP, restart initiated: No, disable resume: No
[0D78:0704][2016-06-27T13:02:39]i399: Apply complete, result: 0x80240017, restart: None, ba requested restart:  No
```

Any idea?

Comment: This is how the problem can be solved:

The prerequisite patch KB 2999226 needs to be installed which can be downloaded from this page:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/dn205267.aspx

"VS2015 Universal C Runtime Prereq KB2999226 64-bit" (or 32-bit)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem recently, I needed to use XAMPP and when initializing the Apache module I received an error "api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0.dll is missing from your computer". I tried  to install "Visual C++ Redistributable" and get the same error "0x80240017" many things to solve this:

- Install all windows updates.
- Download and put the DLL manually in SystemWOW64 folder.
- Install the KBKB2999226 and KB2919355 package that contains this DLL.
- Clear TEMP folder and rename directories.

I could not by any means. What solved my problem was to install Visual Studio 2015 itself, I had to push the envelope, I had to push it, that solved my problem, and XAMPP becomes to run, unfortunately.